# Rendering Facebook Graph Post Data

Tags: asp.net, facebook, json

I am working on an application that requires rendering a Facebook page's posted data. I am using the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) (via Facebook C# SDK) to pull this data in a JSON format. Using something like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGEID}/feed?access_token={ACCESSTOKEN}
```

To give an example of data returned:

```
data": [
{
    "id": "40796308305_250739668349980",
    "from": {
        "name": "Gaboo De Lk",
        "id": "100001297053105"
    },
    "to": {
        "data": [
        {
            "name": "Coca-Cola",
            "category": "Food/beverages",
            "id": "40796308305"
        }
        ]
    },
    "message": "No te gusta el nuevo perfil de Facebook? Aqui tienes la forma para Volver a tu antiguo Perfil a mi me funciono, ESTE SI FUNCIONA http://bit.ly/viejo-perfil\n",
    "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBfA3vq743vkqSw&w=90&h=90&url=http%3A%2F%2Fa7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash2%2F63258_173008029396800_173007416063528_427064_6404507_n.jpg",
    "link": "http://bit.ly/viejo-perfil",
    "name": "!Forma para volver al perfil viejo de Facebook a mi me funciono!!",
    "caption": "www.ircdpr.net",
    "description": "!No te gusta el nuevo perfil de Facebook? Aqui tienes la forma para Volver a tu antiguo Perfil, a mi me funciono ESTE SI FUNCIONA!!",
    "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
    "actions": [
    {
        "name": "Comment",
        "link": "http://www.facebook.com/40796308305/posts/250739668349980"
    },
    {
        "name": "Like",
        "link": "http://www.facebook.com/40796308305/posts/250739668349980"
    }
    ],
    "type": "link",
    "created_time": "2012-03-12T15:52:16+0000",
    "updated_time": "2012-03-12T15:52:16+0000",
    "comments": {
    "count": 0
    },
    "is_published": true
},...]
```

What I am looking for is something provided in ASP.NET, JavaScript, jQuery, or whatever that can render this data in the "Facebook" format so I can render the posted content in as similar fashion as possible to the Facebook page.

Note: You can use Facebook's Graph API Explorer to see the Feed data by getting a [temporary access token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=cocacola/feed).

Comment: Are you looking for us to do the work for you?

Comment: Nope. I've already completed my own custom implementation of this, and I am working on seeing if I can add the created data contracts and helpers to the Facebook C# SDK, but I can't see them accepting it as it's extremely MVC oriented at the moment. My hope is that there is either an open source of Facebook "approved" SDK for rendering this data into HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing I'm aware of (I can be wrong on that) provide you with way of rendering that data in a Facebook alike UI.

The results of API response may change, as well as the UI for Facebook functionality (this one  have minor changes way frequently).

You probably may end up using something custom made mimicking UI that looks like Facebook.

You may read a way old article [How to Style an Application Like Facebook](http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-style-an-application-like-facebook) to have something to start, but this is outdated and many things in Facebook UI changed since then.

My suggestion is not to try mimicking everything about UI you see on Facebook, but provide UI similar to the rest of your application and/or using [Like Box social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) with `stream` option enabled.

Comment: I'm afraid that all the rendering of this data may be custom. I was hoping Facebook had _something_ out there that allowed developers to render all this JSON in a similar fashion so everyone is following the same standard.

Comment: @Crispy724, they are providing this n a form of Like-Box social plugin by providing ability to show stream...

Comment: Yeah, we use the Social Plugins for various parts of the site, but we have one area of the application where streams from various social media sites (Facebook, Twitter, G+, etc.) are all lined up by the posting date, and that's where I'm running into a maintainability problem.

Answer (score 0):

> My hope is that there is either an open source of Facebook "approved" SDK for rendering this data into HTML

No, there is not any "approved" SDK for rendering data.